# How to Pass Complex Type to ASP.NET MVC Controller using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting null values for the complex variable(**RamarksList**) properties with in another Complex type(**Model**).

See the values coming properly for the **Name** and **Type** but I see null values for the properties(Parameter and Comments) for the Complex Type **RemarksList** .

Here is my code. Please take a look and advise.

**jQuery:**

```
 var data = {               
            'Name': 'Apple',
            'Type': 'Fruit',
            'RemarksList': [
              {
                  'Parameter': 'test 1',
                  'Comments': 'test 123'
              },
              {
                  'Parameter': 'test 2',
                  'Comments': 'abc 3455'
              }
            ]
        };



var url = "/Controller/Action";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(Model model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Model classes:

```
public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }      
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type{ get; set; }
        public List<Remarks> RemarksList { get; set; }
    }

public class Remarks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; } 
    public string Comments { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: Tried that. with that I was getting everything null including Type and Name.. not sure why..

Comment: Sorry, you also need `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It is working.. Do I need to set both   dataType: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',?

Comment: `contentType` is for the data you send to the controller and `dataType` is for the data the sever sends back to the client

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

i put your code in my test project, and i get correct data. actually **RemarksList** is not null and works fine!!

[Result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlZsI.jpg)

Comment: W/O content type, was getting RemarksList count as two but Parameter and Comments were NULL. As I mentioned in comment, After adding stringfy and ContentType, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

first convert data in string using JSON.stringify

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

then change controller code from following

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(string model)
        {
           JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           Model routes_list =(Model)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(model);
           return View();
        }
```